# Getting the following error while using React Redux - TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, reducers

I'm working on an e-commerce project using React Redux, and can't seem to get my head around this error that's been bugging me. I'm trying to add the clicked item (along with its props like name, imageUrl, etc.) to the cartItems array through the cart reducer. Created a function to do the adding in utils and trying to import and use that in the reducer (function adds a new prop to the item called quantity to count the frequency of the item). But for some reason, the function is creating some new element with just 1 prop, quantity every time, as opposed to adding the clicked element with the added prop.

My actions component code -

```
import CartActionTypes from './cart.types';

export const toggleCartHidden = () => ({
  type: CartActionTypes.TOGGLE_CART_HIDDEN
});

export const addItem = item => ({
  type: CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM,
  action: item
});
```

cart reducer -

```
import CartActionTypes from './cart.types';
import { addItemToCart } from './cart.utils';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  hidden: true,
  cartItems: []
};

const cartReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CartActionTypes.TOGGLE_CART_HIDDEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        hidden: !state.hidden
      };
    case CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: addItemToCart(state.cartItems, action.payload)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default cartReducer;
```

utils -

```
export const addItemToCart = (cartItems, cartItemToAdd) => {
    const existingCartItem = cartItems.find(
      cartItem => cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
    );
  
    if (existingCartItem) {
      return cartItems.map(cartItem =>
        cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
          ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 }
          : cartItem
        )
    }
  
    return [...cartItems, { ...cartItemToAdd, quantity: 1 }];
  };
```

the collection item component below, which displays the item that should be added (this component is called into the display component which maps the item data to the item component to display all the items). The item clicked should get added with the quantity prop created for the same item through the reducer.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import CustomButton from '../custom-button/custom-button.component';
import { addItem } from '../../Redux/cart/cart.actions';

import './collection-item.styles.css';

const CollectionItem = ({ item, addItem }) => {
  const { name, price, imageUrl } = item;

  return (
    <div className='collection-item'>
      <div
        className='image'
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`
        }}
      />
      <div className='collection-footer'>
        <span className='name'>{name}</span>
        <span className='price'>{price}</span>
      </div>
      <CustomButton onClick={() => addItem(item)} inverted>
        Add to cart
      </CustomButton>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addItem: item => dispatch(addItem(item))
});

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CollectionItem);
```

Collection preview (uses CollectionItem) -

```
import React from 'react';

import CollectionItem from '../collection-item/collection-item.component';

import './collection-preview.styles.css';

const CollectionPreview = ({ title, items }) => (
  <div className='collection-preview'>
    <h1 className='title'>{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
    <div className='preview'>
      {items
        .filter((item, idx) => idx < 4)
        .map(item => (
          <CollectionItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default CollectionPreview;
```

The error screenshot -

[image: the error screenshot]

The right (ADD_ITEM) action is getting triggered and it is capturing that clicked element, but its somehow not getting added to the cartItems array. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did cardItems have id.

Comment: @abhay every cart item does have an id. Since its creating a new item for some reason, it doesn't seem to have one.

Comment: In image next_state cartImtems I only see the quantity value. could you please expand the array?

Comment: can you provide code of file which is using <CollectionItem /> ?

Comment: @abhay thats exactly the problem. Its not adding the clicked item, but creating a new item with only quantity as the prop

Comment: @AllenWong sure

Comment: Your action does not have a ```payload```. It has ```action``` property. So either rename it to ```payload```, or in your reducer change it to ```cartItems: addItemToCart(state.cartItems, action.action)```

Comment: @szczocik addItems action does have a payload thats getting used in the reducer

Comment: @AllenWong I've added the file (actionPreview)

Comment: @Samarth then it should be named ```payload``` in the action object and not action:
```export const addItem = item => ({
  type: CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM,
  action: item
});```

Comment: ```action.payload``` is just a property of the action object. But you are sending an object with properties: ```type``` and ```action```, hence ```payload``` is undefined and the ids are missing

Comment: Remove .payload then do console.log(action)

Comment: I'm accessing values directly through action.I'n one of my project.

const initialState = {
    companySizeTypes: ''
};
export function companySize(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case companySizeConstants.FETCH_COMPANY_SIZE:
            return {
                companySizeTypes:action.companySize.results
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! It's solved. What a silly mistake I had made. Didn't expect so much help so soon. What a wonderful community we have here! Thanks again.